# Rewrite "group by" LINQ without grouping

Tags: sql-server, linq, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm developing a Lightswitch app and need to do view some aggregated data in a screen. However LightSwitch doesn't support "group by" and "sum", so my question is if this could be rewritten without using that.

```
partial void RuleEntriesByUserSaveId_PreprocessQuery(int? UserSaveId, ref IQueryable<RuleEntry> query)
{
   query = query.Where(re => re.Revision == null || re.Revision == UserSaveId)
                .GroupBy(re => re.Key)
                .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Revision != null) ?? g.First());
}
```

I know I can make a WCF RIA Service and use that, but I rather not get into that hassle. Thanks!

Comment: Are standard loops just summarily forgotten about with the rise of Linq?

Comment: Lightswitch does support `Group By` and `Sum`. Just not in the way you are trying to use them. Could you describe your entity fields and what you are trying to accomplish? It's not clear from your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging more into this issue it's clear that grouping **can't** be done in the PreprocessQuery function. If you need aggregation of data you're bound to use some sort of abstraction of the data layer. I managed to do this by adding a WCF RIA Service as in [this guide](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/how-to-use-wcf-ria-service-in-lightswitch-2012/). It requires some time for understanding but it's definitely worth the effort in the end!